# qgis web client zoom and center maps

Tags: qgis

I have a problem with " qgis web client" I can not find the option setting center of maps and change the zoom ?? I was looking at globaloptions but I managed to ; /
Regards

Answer (score 1):

QWC is setup to open with the extent that's saved in the .qgs project.

So, you can fix this QGIS project side by going to the Project->Project properties->OWS Server and setup the Service Capabilities but also the CRS restrictions (make sure the CRS of your client e.g. 3857 is the first in the CRS restrictions, otherwise QWC won't respect the zoom level and extent).